# Starting up your Nuxt PWA with a particular route

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps

My nuxt `web application` is part of the `main website`, but we want the web app to be installable as `a PWA`, is there a way that after I install it, whenever I want to launch the app on my phone, it redirects to a different route, for example, '`www.example.com/login`' instead of the homepage '`www.example.com`'.

Comment: Wouldn't always directing users to the `login` page be annoying if they're already logged in? Can you not just detect the user state using a route navigation guard and redirect to `login` if required?

Comment: that's what is happening, but the web app itself is part of a general website, I don't want that when they launch the app it goes to the home website, rather to /login and if they're logged straight to the app home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `manifest.json` you can set a `"start_url"` field. In your case, I think, the solution will be: `"start_url": "/login"`